# Setting the string value of 'myTerm' based on various cell content combinations

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Is it possible to set the value of `myTerm` using a series of `If` statements?

I have 3 columns in a worksheet which will have data added to them over the course of the year.

I have the following scenarios:

K has data and M & O = "Autumn"
K and M have data and O is empty = "Spring"
K, M and O all have data = Summer

I have written the following (a snippet of the full code):

```
Sub FilterProgressData()

    Dim myTerm As String

    If SrcWs.Cells(i, "O").Value = "" And SrcWs.Cells(i, "M").Value = "" And _
        SrcWs.Cells(i, "K").Value <> "" Then
            myTerm = "Autumn"

    ElseIf SrcWs.Cells(i, "O").Value = "" And SrcWs.Cells(i, "M").Value <> "" _
        And SrcWs.Cells(i, "K").Value <> "" Then
            myTerm = "Spring"

    ElseIf SrcWs.Cells(i, "O").Value <> "" And SrcWs.Cells(i, "M").Value <> "" _
        And SrcWs.Cells(i, "K").Value <> "" Then
            myTerm = "Summer"
```

but get a 'Run-time error '1004' error - Application-defined or object-defined error'

Any advice will be gratefully received!

Thanks.

Comment: Your error has little to nothing to do with the fact that you are using `If` statements. Without a [mcve] it is impossible to tell what is causing the error. The problem almost certainly lies in code that you have decided to not show.

Comment: What is Variable SrcWs?  It needs to be defined. If it is a worksheet then you need. Dim SrcWs As Worksheet.

Comment: Thank you for these comments - the other variables are defined and set appropriately, I was trying to give you the minimal code that i have added which caused the error when testing. I'll try the change as outlined below and, if I still have issues, will post a fuller version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. I do not see a problem with your if statement.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterProgressData()
Dim myTerm As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim SrcWs As Worksheet
Set SrcWs = Worksheets("Sheet1")

i = 1

    If SrcWs.Cells(i, "O").Value = "" And SrcWs.Cells(i, "M").Value = "" And _
        SrcWs.Cells(i, "K").Value <> "" Then
            myTerm = "Autumn"

    ElseIf SrcWs.Cells(i, "O").Value = "" And SrcWs.Cells(i, "M").Value <> "" _
        And SrcWs.Cells(i, "K").Value <> "" Then
            myTerm = "Spring"

    ElseIf SrcWs.Cells(i, "O").Value <> "" And SrcWs.Cells(i, "M").Value <> "" _
        And SrcWs.Cells(i, "K").Value <> "" Then
            myTerm = "Summer"

    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues that I could see in your snippet:

- `SrcWs` is not declared/instantiated anywhere in your snippet.
- `i` is not assigned. If it's being implicitly converted to `0` (when using `Cells()`), then you're trying to access the zeroth row of the worksheet (which doesn't exist and will give you an error).

Say you want to assign a value to `myTerm` based on the values in columns K, M, O and rows 1 to 100 (for example's sake). You could then try something like the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConditionallyAssignMyTerm()
    Dim SrcWs As Worksheet
    Set SrcWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim i As Long ' Might be better to rename this to rowIndex or something more descriptive than just i

    With SrcWs
        Dim myTerm As String

        Dim columnKisBlank As Boolean
        Dim columnMisBlank As Boolean
        Dim columnOisBlank As Boolean

        For i = 1 To 100 ' Arbitrary loop values
            columnKisBlank = CellIsBlank(.Cells(i, "K"))
            columnMisBlank = CellIsBlank(.Cells(i, "M"))
            columnOisBlank = CellIsBlank(.Cells(i, "O"))

            If (Not columnKisBlank) And columnMisBlank And columnOisBlank Then
                myTerm = "Autumn"

            ElseIf (Not columnKisBlank) And (Not columnMisBlank) And columnOisBlank Then
                myTerm = "Spring"

            ElseIf (Not columnKisBlank) And (Not columnMisBlank) And (Not columnOisBlank) Then
                myTerm = "Summer"
            End If
        Next i

    End With
End Sub

Function CellIsBlank(ByRef cellToCheck As Range) As Boolean
    CellIsBlank = VBA.IsEmpty(cellToCheck.Value2) Or (Len(cellToCheck.Value2) = 0)
End Function
```